# ASP.NET Mvc3 - application/request lifetime and dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-3

I thought of asking on SO, but it seems this is more of a "concept" type question than a "problem" type question. If it needs to be moved, please do so.

Anyway, I'm having a tough time finding straight info on this. I'm using [Unity.Mvc3](http://unitymvc3.codeplex.com/) to setup dependency injection for controllers and other components the controllers might use.

From what I understand from the Unity.Mvc3 website, anything that is `IDisposable` will be disposed at the end of the request from the container if it is registered with a `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`.

Does that mean that things registered with the `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` will be registered as the same instance for all requests for as long as the server/application is running?

Can I register an instance using the `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` or does it have to be a type?

How do the application/session/request lifetimes work? I ask, because I come from PHP and PHP has no scope outside the request, so this is obviously something I need to get a hang of.

Comment: In general, ASP.NET MVC (if done correctly) doesn't have scope outside the request either.  The description on the `Unity.MVC` page says this; it  *"creates a child container per HTTP request and disposes of all registered IDisposable instances at the end of the request."*

Comment: @RobertHarvey The "(if done correctly)" part is what worries me. Are there some common pitfalls that one must be careful of, or is this question a bit too broad?

Comment: The most common pitfalls are those that occur when treating ASP.NET MVC 3 like it is ASP.NET Webforms, where there is implied saving of state between requests.  State is persisted, but it's not generally done in the `Session` object, or anywhere else but the data repository.  Each request is a "transaction" in its own right; it starts when the request is made, and ends when the request is complete.